# Files will not delete

Tags: permissions, delete

I have a folder with photos init which I can not delete.
It has 3 files at the start with names such as ·b#╣9%r.t and 6 files as such at the end.
These files a 2gig or bigger.
I have copied the photos out so anything dangerous will do.
chmod, rm, rmdir etc give me read only access.
I cannot open them.
Last note: The copied out files give me a read only response although I can access them and the permissions are normal.
I might add having to use only pre used tags shows why the questions here are so standardised.

Post Edit: Further info / reply:
/media/fh/SATA500/NikonPhotos 2021/Feb28 l135 l60 ls -la

```
Top of file list:
ls: cannot access '█XIΣ┬`²╟.'\'''\''ù': Input/output error
ls: cannot access 'é'$'\003''≤è#ï±'$'\021''.Åφφ': Input/output error
ls: cannot access '0≡8x╜²▓≤.!qτ': Input/output error
ls: reading directory '.': Input/output error
total 18409632
drwxr-xr-x 232 fh fh      32768 Feb 28 12:29  .
drwxr-xr-x  16 fh fh      32768 Apr 19 18:08  ..
d?????????   ? ?  ?           ?            ? '0≡8x╜²▓≤.!qτ'
-rw-r--r--   1 fh fh 2827245013 Feb 11  2031 '╦%à┴!¥┴'$'\005''.·íσ'
-r--r--r--   1 fh fh 3151126565 Jan 13  2068 '·b#╣9%'$'\177''r.t'$'\v\022'
Bottom of file list:
-rw-r--r--   1 fh fh   26903915 Feb 28 10:03  D61_0612.NEF
d?????????   ? ?  ?           ?            ? 'é'$'\003''≤è#ï±'$'\021''.Åφφ'
-r--r--r--   1 fh fh 1945285026 May  4  2008  ╔òï╩▒⌠ä└.╔ò≈
-r--r--r--   1 fh fh 3862189846 Dec  2  2019 'ötß.ñ╤?▓.Q8£'
-rw-r--r--   1 fh fh  547716179 May 21  2045 'ô₧╩╖'$'\003''<`&.σ╠'$'\021'
-r--r--r--   1 fh fh 2440913345 Jan  2  2077 '╖û'$'\n''c╫'$'\v''9'$'\f''.â╬═'
d?????????   ? ?  ?           ?            ? '█XIΣ┬`²╟.'\'''\''ù'

lsattr:
lsattr: Inappropriate ioctl for device While reading flags on ./D61_0612.NEF
lsattr: Inappropriate ioctl for device While reading flags on ./·b#╣9%r.t
                                                                         
lsattr: Inappropriate ioctl for device While reading flags on ./ô₧╩╖<`&.σ╠
./█XIΣ┬`²╟.''ù: Input/output error
./é≤è#ï±.Åφφ: Input/output error
lsattr: Inappropriate ioctl for device While reading flags on ./╦%à┴!¥┴.·íσ
lsattr: Inappropriate ioctl for device While reading flags on ./ötß.ñ╤?▓.Q8£
lsattr: Inappropriate ioctl for device While reading flags on ./╖û
c╫
  9
   .â╬═
lsattr: Inappropriate ioctl for device While reading flags on ./╔òï╩▒⌠ä└.╔ò≈
./0≡8x╜²▓≤.!qτ: Input/output error
```

Answer to Rinzwind:
disk is internal: i have left off 30 or so files in the middle.
It is formatted as f32 and i don't have or use windows.
It is a 1 terabyte drive and these files are grouped as 3 at the top of the folder and 6 at the bottom of the folder. the file sizes are 2 gig or more.

Comment: add `sudo` to your `rm` command...If you type `ls -la` in that directory it will probably show the owner as `root:root`

Comment: And `lsattr /path/to/one/of/this/file`

Comment: I have done all the obvious stuff like su, sudo, rm, rmdir, etc.

Comment: sudo chattr -i ### ?    https://www.howtoforge.com/linux-chattr-command/

Comment: Mount the external disk properly please. You got errors on that disk. If it is NTFS use windows to fix it